# Вставка столбца в определенную строку

Tags: sql-server, запрос

Опыта в написании запросов 0, поэтому не знаю, как реализовать следующую вещь: есть много строк и известен первичный ключ определенной строки. Нужно вставить столбец именно строку с данным ключом. Если писать просто `INSERT INTO TAB(c) VALUES v`, то строка вставляется в конец. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Наверно Вам нужен [UPDATE](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/update.html)?

```
UPDATE Table SET field1=value1, field2=value2 WHERE id=value3
```

Comment: Точно,спасибо.